# Quantity Picker is not working in Gatsby Failed to Compile

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, picker

I'm trying to create a quantity picker to use in Gatsby but keep getting this failed to compile message regarding the value variable.

> ./src/components/quantityPicker.js Module Error (from
>   ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> /Users/tolleyl/Documents/strangedonuts/strange-donuts/src/components/quantityPicker.js
>   18:36  warning  Unexpected labeled statement
>   no-labels   18:36  warning  'value:' is defined but never used
>   no-unused-labels   18:43  error    Expected an assignment or function
>   call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> ✖ 3 problems (1 error, 2 warnings)   0 errors and 1 warning
>   potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

My code is below.

```
import React from 'react'
import "../components/qty-picker.scss"

class Quantity extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {value : 1}
      this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
      this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    }

    increment() {
      this.setState(prevState => {value: ++prevState.value});
    }

    decrement() {
      this.setState(prevState => { value: prevState.value > 0? --prevState.value : 0});
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <div>
          <p>
          Set the quantity
         </p>
        <div className="quantity-input">
          <button className="quantity-input__modifier quantity-input__modifier--left" onClick={this.decrement}>
            &mdash;
          </button>
          <input className="quantity-input__screen" type="text" value={this.state.value} readonly />
          <button className="quantity-input__modifier quantity-input__modifier--right" onClick={this.increment}>
            &#xff0b;
          </button>  
        </div>  
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default Quantity;
```

Comment: I suggest you take another look at those `setState` statements, `=> {}` vs `=> ({})`. Good luck!

Comment: @Valentin it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer helped you out, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using arrow functions you need to be mindful about the difference between `() => {...}` which executes the code between the curly brackets and `() => ({...})` which returns an object described in the brackets.

In your case changing the `setState` lines to `this.setState(prevState => ({ ... }))` will resolve the issue.

Note: Added this as an answer after hinting at the solution in the comments.